# Selected value of Radio Button doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In the view, I have these two radio buttons:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.CampaignType, "Exclusive")<label>Exclusive</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.CampaignType, "Shared")<label>Shared</label>
```

The value for `Model.CampaignType` is set in the controller before the page loads.  All of this works fine.  If `Exclusive` is what's saved in the DB, then we get this rendered in the HTML:

```
<input checked="checked" id="CampaignType" name="CampaignType" type="radio" value="Exclusive"><label>Exclusive</label>
<input id="CampaignType" name="CampaignType" type="radio" value="Shared"><label>Shared</label>
```

So far, all's well.

But, inside an onclick() event for a button, if I do this:

```
var values = 
    {
        "CampaignType": $('#CampaignType').val()
    }
alert(values.CampaignType);
```

The alert always comes up as `Exclusive', even if I have changed the selection to 'Shared'.

What do I need to do so that `values.CampaignType` reflects the what is selected on the page, and not what was set when the page was loaded?

Comment: you have the *same* `id` for both `input`s...

Comment: ookkkayy... so,  maybe back to MVC radio buttons 101?  I thought they needed the same id to be in the same group?  Meaning, so if one is checked, the other is unchecked. They are both populated from the same object in the model: CampaignType

Comment: you are talking about the `name` attribute and *not* `id`...

Comment: The name attribute groups radio buttons, names don't need to be unique.

Comment: Use `$(:radio[name="CampaignType"]:checked').val()`

Comment: Thanks Azim.  If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you can do start with these:

1. Remove the invalid `id`s - multiple `id`s are *invalid* in CSS. For getting the value of the *checked* radio button you can use:

   ```
   $('input[name=CampaignType]:checked').val()
   ```

   or

   ```
   $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()
   ```
2. For the `label` to work you have to *link* it with the corresponding radio button using the `for` attribute.

See demo below:

```js
function submit() {
  var values = {
    "CampaignType": $('input[name=CampaignType]:checked').val()
  }
  console.log(values.CampaignType);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input checked="checked" id="CampaignType1" name="CampaignType" type="radio" value="Exclusive">
<label for="CampaignType1">Exclusive</label>
<input id="CampaignType2" name="CampaignType" type="radio" value="Shared">
<label for="CampaignType2">Shared</label>
<br/>
<button onclick="submit()">click here</button>
```

All the best!